# Creating Keycloak Realm via Ansible

Tags: ansible, keycloak

Currently there is no module to create a Keycloak realm with Ansible. There is a PR but it is stucked since half a year or so. So I though, there is a Keycloak REST API (https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/9.0/rest-api/index.html#_realms_admin_resource) and I could call it with `uri` to create a Token and then send a JSON RealmRepresentation via REST. So I tried this:

```
- name: "Create Token for service Keycloak"
  uri:
    url: "https://keycloak-server/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
    method: POST
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    body:
      username: "admin"
      password: "password"
      grant_type: "password"
      client_id: "admin-cli"
  register: keycloak_token

- name: "Create Realm for service Keycloak"
  uri:
    url: "https://keycloak-server/auth/"
    method: POST
    src: "realm.json"
    remote_src: "no"
    headers:
      Content-type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ keycloak_token.json.access_token }}"
  register: keycloak_realm_create
```

The token is available within `keycloak_token.json.access_token` and it is correct.

As `realm.json` I tested a minimal JSON (because all attributes in RealmRepresentation are marked as optional):

```
{
  "id": "myrealm",
  "realm": "myrealm",
  "displayName": "My Realm",
  "enabled": true,
  "sslRequired": "external",
  "registrationAllowed": false,
  "loginWithEmailAllowed": true,
  "duplicateEmailsAllowed": false,
  "resetPasswordAllowed": false,
  "editUsernameAllowed": false,
  "bruteForceProtected": true
}
```

or a complete JSON export from Keycloak via WebUI (export realm).

But in any case the following error happens:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": false, 
  "connection": "close", 
  "content": "{\"error\":\"RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type\"}", 
  "content_length": "55", 
  "content_type": "application/json", 
  "elapsed": 0, 
  "json": {"error": "RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type"},
  "msg": "Status code was 415 and not [200]: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type",
  "redirected": false,
  "status": 415,
  "url": "https://keycloak-server/auth/"
}
```

The documentation says it must be a `POST` to `/` and it consumes `application/json`. So, I'm not sure - is the URL correct? If I try `https://keycloak-server/auth/realms/`, I'm getting a 404. If I remove the `Content-type` - I'm getting a 406 with "Not acceptable". If I remove Accepts too, I'm getting a HTML page.

So - what is wrong?

Comment: I think the endpoint should be `https://keycloak-server/auth/admin/realms`? What happens if you try with CURL something like this `curl -v -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d @realm.json \
  $KCHOST/auth/admin/realms`?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, if I add the `/admin/` between auth and realms, it works. I'll write an answer with a complete example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JSapkota mentioned the URL was wrong. It must be `https://keycloak-server/auth/admin/realms`.

```
- name: "Create Realm for service Keycloak"
  uri:
    url: "https://keycloak-server/auth/admin/realms"
    method: POST
    src: "realm.json"
    remote_src: "no"
    status_code:
     - 201
    headers:
      Content-type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ keycloak_token.json.access_token }}"
  register: keycloak_realm_create
```

Take care about the return status code. It is "201 created" and the `uri` module must know, that this is fine.

This works one time. Because in the next run the REST API responses with 409 the `uri` module fails. 
To be idempotent, you need to check first, if the realm exists. This can be done via `GET /auth/admin/realms/{{ keycloak_realm_name }}` and check the return code, if it is 404 or 200. If it is 404, then you make a "POST" otherwise a "PUT". So, this a complete example:

```
- name: "Set facts"
  set_fact:
    keycloak_admin_user: "admin"
    keycloak_admin_pass: "password"
    keycloak_base_url: "https://keycloak.server"
    keycloak_realm_name: "myrealm"
    keycloak_realm_data_file: "realm.json"

- name: "Create Token for service Keycloak"
  uri:
    url: "{{ keycloak_base_url }}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
    method: POST
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    body:
      username: "{{ keycloak_admin_user }}"
      password: "{{ keycloak_admin_pass }}"
      grant_type: "password"
      client_id: "admin-cli"
  register: keycloak_token

- name: "Find out, if Realm {{ keycloak_realm_name }} for service Keycloak exists"
  uri:
    url: "{{ keycloak_base_url }}/auth/admin/realms/{{ keycloak_realm_name }}"
    method: GET
    status_code:
     - 200
     - 404
    headers:
      Accept: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ keycloak_token.json.access_token }}"
  register: keycloak_realm_exists

- name: "Create Realm {{ keycloak_realm_name }} for service Keycloak"
  uri:
    url: "{{ keycloak_base_url }}/auth/admin/realms"
    method: POST
    src: "{{ keycloak_realm_data_file }}"
    remote_src: "no"
    status_code:
     - 201
    headers:
      Content-type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ keycloak_token.json.access_token }}"
  register: keycloak_realm_create
  when: "keycloak_realm_exists.status == 404"

- name: "Update Realm {{ keycloak_realm_name }} for service Keycloak"
  uri:
    url: "{{ keycloak_base_url }}/auth/admin/realms/{{ keycloak_realm_name }}"
    method: PUT
    src: "{{ keycloak_realm_data_file }}"
    remote_src: "no"
    status_code:
     - 204
    headers:
      Content-type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ keycloak_token.json.access_token }}"
  register: keycloak_realm_create
  when: "keycloak_realm_exists.status == 200"
```

Also I had the problem, that after every request the Keycloak server responses with a 403 when I don't refresh the token before the next call to Keycloak. But I think, this depends on Realm token settings of the admin realm.